# PostgreSQL: back-up table has different ID from parent

Tags: postgresql, triggers, rules

We are using `DO ALSO RULEs` in PostgreSQL to create auditing  (history) tables.

What I've noticed is that when I have a `SERIAL` column, the values are "shared" between the parent and audit tables (hence you cannot use the value to `JOIN` the tables).

I've created by audit tables with the `CREATE TABLE abc AS SELECT * FROM def...`

How can I ensure that the `SERIAL` column have the same value between the two tables?

**EDIT, here is the complete test case**

**STEP 1 - create the parent table** (the one to be audit / history tracking)

```
CREATE TABLE audit_testing_parent (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    varchar_col1 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    varchar_col2 VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    int_col INTEGER,
    created_on TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

**STEP 2 - INSERT some data**

```
INSERT INTO audit_testing_parent(varchar_col1, varchar_col2, int_col)
VALUES ('test01','test01',1);
```

**STEP 3 - CREATE an auditing table**

```
CREATE TABLE audit_testing_audit
AS SELECT 'INSERT' audit_Type, NOW() audit_time, a.*
   FROM audit_testing_parent a
;
```

**STEP 4 - CREATE a RULE to audit the parent's data**

```
create rule audit_testing_parent_on_insert as on insert to audit_testing_parent do also
insert into audit_testing_audit
(
    audit_type,
    audit_time,
    id,
    varchar_col1,
    varchar_col2,
    int_col,
    created_on
)
values
(
'INSERT',
now(),
    new.id,
    new.varchar_col1,
    new.varchar_col2,
    new.int_col,
    new.created_on
);
```

**STEP 4 - Test the RULE by performing another INSERT**

```
INSERT INTO audit_testing_parent(varchar_col1, varchar_col2, int_col)
VALUES ('test02','test02',2);
```

The parent table now looks like this:
[image: parent table]

The audit table looks like this:
[image: audit table]

Note the difference in the ID column.

In the parent table, the row where the `int_col = 2` the `id = 2`

But the same row in the audit table (`int_col = 2`), the `id = 3`

How can I ensure that the `RULE` handles the `SERIAL` column so that both tables have the same value in the ID column?

Comment: That is unclear: o you want the columns to be the same or not? Your `CREATE TABLE` will copy all rows, so all the columns will be identical.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz Albe, I want the values to be the same across the 2 tables, but they seem to be using the same sequence. When I create the initial table all values are exactly the same. However, when I do an INSERT into the parent, the RULE does an INSERT into the audit table. In this table the serial columns' values differ. Both seem to select the next value from a sequence for each of the INSERTs.

Comment: The table you created with `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT` will have no default value defined. You should edit the question and tell us how you use the sequence to populate the tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response @LaurenzAlbe, I made the edit and added all the steps for my test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work, because that's not how rules work. If you insert `nextval('someseq')` into your main table, the rule will do the same thing for the audit table, so you will get the next sequence value.

The solution is not to use a rule for this, but a trigger.